# Common button component in React native creating issue with axios api calls

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, axios, redux-saga

I have made a common button component which I am using in two different pages.
On click of the button it calls different API depending on props.

Sometimes,the button doesn't call the API it is supposed to call.It calls the previous API that was called from another page.

I checked and I came to solution that asynchronous axios request needs to be unsubscribed but I am not sure where to unsubscribe the API call and how.

I am using redux saga to make Api calls.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Image, Icon} from 'react-native-elements';


const Button = props => {
  handlePress = () => {
    props.onPress();
  };

  return (
    <>
        <Button
          title={props.title}
          onPress={() => this.handlePress()}
          icon={
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/images/abc.png')}
              style={{marginLeft: ResponsiveWidth(-41)}}
            />
          }></Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

In components(1 and 2) I am using this button as below

```
<Button onPress={this.handleSubmit}    //Handle submit dispatches different action from component 1 and component 2
```

Comment: whats the issue that you are facing?any errors?

Comment: if `this.handleSubmit` is not arrow function you can face with such issue or is not binded like this in constructor `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom button

```
const MyButton = ({title,onPress}) => {
  return (
       <Button
          title={title}
          onPress={onPress}
          icon={
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/images/abc.png')}
              style={{marginLeft: ResponsiveWidth(-41)}}
            />
          }>
        </Button>
  );
};

export default MyButton;
```

And call it:

```
<MyButton title={'Title'} onPress={()=> doJob()} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel a request using a cancel token.

1) You can create a cancel token using the CancelToken.source factory as shown below:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).catch(function (thrown) {
  if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});

axios.post('/user/12345', {
  name: 'new name'
}, {
  cancelToken: source.token
})

source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

2) You can also create a cancel token by passing an executor function to the CancelToken constructor:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
    // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
    cancel = c;
  })
});

// cancel the request

cancel();
```